Two identical constructors however compiler selects the templated one
I am trying to implement a list container in C++, and I have problem with compiler selecting the wrong constructor overload.
The constructors are as follows:
list(size_type count, const T& value);

template<typename InputIt>
list(InputIt begin, InputIt end);

When I initialize the object in the source file, I can not prevent the compiler from selecting the second overload:
list<int> x(5, 45);

The second overload should be selected when the given arguments are iterators. However, I can't accomplish it.

EDIT: The class declaration looks like this:
template<typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>> 
class list 
{
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = T*;
    using const_pointer = const T*;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;
    using move_reference = T&&; // custom
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

    list(size_type count, const T& value);

    template<typename InputIt>
    list(InputIt begin, InputIt end);
    // ...
};


What are size_type and T in the first declaration?

Since the class declaration is pretty big, I didn't mention in the post. However, it looks like this: "template<typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator> class list{};" so it is int here

What is size_type?

Well, from the looks of it, you're explicitly calling the templated function with int as parameter. The fact that you called the parameter InputIt doesn't mean anything to the compiler.

5 is int and doesn't match size_type, and the second template is selected with the exact match InputIt as int.

SFINAE on Iterable for second overload.

list<int> x(std::size_t{5}, 45);, or C++23 list<int> x(5uz, 45);

@Jarod42 your answer is correct but the people who can understand it are exactly those people who don't need it.

@JeJo ...which doesn't make any practical difference for the Q


The second overload should be selected when the given arguments are iterable however I can't accomplish it?

You need to SFINAE ("Substitution Failure Is Not An Error") one of the constructors (prior to C++20), so that correct constructors will be chosen.
// Constructor for iterator range
template<typename InputIt
    , std::enable_if_t<
           std::is_constructible_v<
               T, typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type>>* = nullptr
           >
    list(InputIt begin, InputIt end)
    /* : contr init list */
{}

See live demo

In C++20, however, just constrain the constructor for std::input_or_output_iterator:
template<typename InputIt>
    requires (std::input_or_output_iterator<InputIt>)
list(InputIt begin, InputIt end) 
  /* : contr init list */
{}

See live demo

The problem is that the templated ctor is a better match because it is an exact match for both the passed arguments 5 and 45 while the non-templated ctor requires a conversion from int (signed int) to size_type (unsigned long) for the first argument 5.
There are multiple way of solving this as shown in the other answer. In particular, with c++20 you can use std::input_or_output_iterator on the templated ctor to constrain it.

This is an old problem. In the declarations as you've written them, the constructor template gives a better match because both arguments have type int and the constructor template can be instantiated with InputIt equal to int, whereas for the non-template constructor, a conversion would need to occur from int to size_type (which I assume is something like std::size_t).
In C++98, the problem was solved by specifying that if InputIt is an integral type, then the constructor template behaves as if it calls the other constructor, rather than treating the integral type as an iterator (which, of course, would be ill-formed, since you can't dereference values of integral type). In C++11, the specification was changed to say that integer types and some unspecified set of additional types determined by the library are considered to not qualify as input iterators, and in those cases the iterator-pair constructor doesn't participate in overload resolution. This allows (but doesn't require) the library to use expression SFINAE (or perhaps just C++98-style SFINAE, e.g., if std::iterator_traits<I>::type isn't a valid type, then I isn't an iterator type). This specification persists to the current day. Although C++20 has an actual concept called std::input_iterator, the C++20 iterator concepts are not exactly the same as the "legacy" iterator requirements (known as e.g. Cpp17InputIterator) that apply to the pre-ranges APIs for containers and algorithms, which were left unchanged for backward compatibility reasons. So the iterator-pair constructors were not given a constraint that the iterator type satisfies the std::input_iterator concept.
Here's an example of something you might write in order to constrain the constructor template for your own sequence container:
template <typename InputIt>
list(InputIt begin, InputIt end)
requires(std::is_base_of_v<std::input_iterator_tag,
                           typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::iterator_category> &&
         std::is_convertible_v<decltype(*begin), T>);

The first part checks that InputIt's iterator category is at least as strong as std::input_iterator_tag (it can be something stronger, like std::random_access_iterator_tag. The second part checks that a T can be copy-initialized from the type and value category obtained by dereferencing the iterator type. This requires-expression doesn't fully check all the input iterator requirements, but it's good enough to prevent this constructor from getting called for a pair of arithmetic types.
